# mongodb coalesce equivalent (with mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a **localization** collection where each document is a key-value pair translated into multiple languages.

This is a JSON representation:

```
[
  { "_id": "form.password" , "en": "Password"  , "he": "סיסמא"  , "ru": "пароль" }
  { "_id": "form.email"    , "en": "Email"     , "he": "אימייל" },
  { "_id": "form.firstname", "en": "First Name", "he": "שם פרטי", "ru": "Имя" }
]
```

This is a mongoose schema:

```js
new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  en: String,
  he: String,
  ru: String
});
```

I need to get all key-values per each language with express.js:

```js
app.get('/api/locals', function(req, res) {
  Local.find().select( req.query.language ).exec(function(err, data) {
    res.json(data);
  });
});
```

This works fine **if each language has the values for all keys** but I want to make a **fallback** where if some language has no value for a certain key then the english value will be used.

I thought maybe I should use aggregation or mapReduce but I don't know how to implement this with mongoose.

With SQL I used to write this query:

```sql
SELECT key, COALESCE($language , en) as value FROM locals
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There isn't one yet, there is a JIRA for this but I have forgotten where it is now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution with the [Aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/):

Using [**$project**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) with [**$ifNull**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/):

```
app.get('/api/locals', function(req, res) {
  Local.aggregate({
    $project: {
      value: {
        $ifNull: ["$" + req.query.language , "$en"]
      }
    }
  }).exec(function(err, data) {
    res.json(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: It is one way but unfortunately it is actually just as slow as doing it in the application maybe if not slower since more has to be computed

Comment: @Sammaye Can you explain why it is slow?

Comment: Full collection scan for one, also it calls MongoDB to just do something that would be just as fast application side